# UnrecognizedPropertyException map to JSONObject

Tags: java, typescript, exception

currently I am programming a stocks project for my Bachelor degree, but I'm stuck.
For Frontend I use Angular and Backend Java with a Postgres DB.

I'm getting a 500 response when I try to update a row in my DB. The error is

org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "empty" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

In Angular I have a Watchlist Interface, which I want to update with an additional investment in it, send the new Watchlist to the backend, to store it in the db.

```
export interface Watchlist{
  id?: number,
  userid?: number,
  watchlist?: any
}
```

on button click in the template I access the following method.

```
hinzufuegenWatchlist(){
    this.mainComponent.watchlist.watchlist[this.isin] = this.investment;
    this.watchlistService.sendRequestUpdateWatchlist(this.mainComponent.watchlist)
      .subscribe(response => console.log('Investment zur Watchlist hinzugefügt'));
  }

sendRequestUpdateWatchlist(watchlist : Watchlist){
    return this.http
      .put<Investment>(this.getServiceURL().concat("updateWatchlist"), JSON.stringify(watchlist),this.getOptions())
  }
```

In the backend I use a JSONObject for the watchlist. The idea is to store every investment with its isin as an accessible key, to easily check whether its already stored or not. And easily store the whole watchlist in one row in the DB:

```
public class Watchlist {
    private int id;
    private int userid;
    private JSONObject watchlist;
```

```
@PUT
    @Path("updateWatchlist")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void updateWatchlist(Watchlist watchlist){
        try {
            String sql = "UPDATE watchlistdb set watchlist=? where id=?";
            PreparedStatement ps = DatabaseHelper.connectDatabase().prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,watchlist.getWatchlist().toString());
            ps.setInt(2,watchlist.getId());
            ps.execute();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My first thoughts are, that it can't be mapped because it isn't a standard Java type like string or int. But how can I solve that problem?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: In my opinion you should try using Object type. What is output after that?

Comment: I had the same problem, and the reason for it was that I had a method name `isEmpty()` in my class => spring thought that the class would have an private boolean named empty because of the "is" word. If you change the method name to something that doesn't start with "is", e.g. `checkIfEmpty()` the problem would go away.